# Upload video to facebook fail with larger files

Tags: facebook-graph-api, asp.net-mvc-5, facebook-sdk-4.0

I built a feature allowing to upload video to facebook from my website (through my server, which means I "upload twice"). I tested it sever times and it works just fine (I test with a small video, about 3 MB), but every time I try to upload larger video (56 MB) the upload fails. I ran a debugger, and found out it fails while the debugger is in this line (uploading the video to facebook)

```
dynamic result = fb.Post(groupId + "/videos", parameters);
```

with the following exeption: "The request was aborted: The request was canceled."

here is my code:

```
public string UploadVideoToGroup(string accessToken, string filePath, string fileType, string title, string description, byte[] file)
    {
        string groupId = _config.FacebookGroupId;


        var fb = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
        dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();

        parameters.source = new FacebookMediaObject { ContentType = fileType, FileName = filePath }.SetValue(file);
        parameters.title = title;
        parameters.description = description;

        dynamic result = fb.Post(groupId + "/videos", parameters);

        string id = "";
        try
        {
            id = result.id;
        }
        catch
        {
            return "";

        }
        return id;
    }
```

Im not sure where the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-csharp-sdk/issues/181), it is recommended to use FacebookMediaStream instead of the byte array, and use `PostAsync` or `PostTaskAsync` instead of `Post`.